# How to get data from URL using php with each of the next pages

Tags: php

I have a link https://vi.wiktionary.org/wiki/Th%E1%BB%83_lo%E1%BA%A1i:M%E1%BB%A5c_t%E1%BB%AB_ti%E1%BA%BFng_Vi%E1%BB%87t
Can someone help me how to get all data from this link with each of the next pages?

Comment: This is called "web scraping", you can read a lot about it if you Google that phrase

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: But there are many more pages to come. Do you have a way to get data from all those pages, like "Trang sau" as the next page.